# KeyError: 'Key' and TypeError: An Integer is required

Tags: python, pandas, azure

Both of these questions have been answered I believe but I am currently getting both of these errors in one run and I am not sure what caused it.

```
# Get data
fileName = 'https://acmsmlblob.blob.core.windows.net/acmsdata/resultExpandedGlbFriendlyName_1.ss_TOP_10000.csv'
raw = pd.read_csv(fileName, ",", header=None)
df = raw.copy()

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDateId'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
df['dow'] = df['datetime'].dt.dayofweek
df['tod'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour
df = df[['dow', 'tod', 'Owner', 'TenantId', 'SplitedPolicy']]
```

When I run the above code it produces me these errors and since I have absolutely no idea how Python works I am having troubling deciphering why they are thrown.

```
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError: 'StartDateId'
```

Is there any reason why this is happening from the code

Comment: Can you run df.columns right before the df['datetime'] line, and tell me if 'StartDateId' is part of the column?

Answer (score 2):

You are telling pandas to ignore the headers on the csv file:

```
raw = pd.read_csv(fileName, ",", header=None)
```

As a result it doesn't know the column names and wants an integer index. The file has a header row, so don't ignore it and you should be able to use the header names:

```
raw = pd.read_csv(fileName, ",")
```